# Intellisense not working for one connection but works for others

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, intellisense

I can connect to multiple database servers. Intellisense works on all of the connections except one. It used to work on this connection also until recently.

I did the following:

- Enable Intellisense (on the toolbar and edit > intellisense)
- Disable and then enable intellisense
- Install SP3
- Reboot SQL (and PC)

Comment: Did you try this? [Troubleshooting IntelliSense (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173434.aspx)

Comment: Is it in a remote location? Over a slow network? What is the version of the destination server (`@@VERSION`)? What is the version of SSMS in Help -> About? Where did you apply SP3, on the client, server, or both (and if you really mean 2008 and not 2008 R2, did you mean SP4)? Are you using SQL authentication or Windows authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

If so, look at this Microsoft Support article:

[FIX: The IntelliSense feature in SSMS 2008 R2 may stop working after you install Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2531482)

The fix was first released in Cumulative Update package 7 for SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM. It is included in all later updates and service packs. If you have indeed applied Service Pack 3 for SQL Server 2008 R2, you already have this fix.